# Grouped Gridview

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview, listview

I am in the process of transitioning an Access DB to a Web application. The Access DB currently produces reports using grouping e.g.:

```
Country
-------------------------------------------------------
County
-------------------------------------------------------
City Name | Population | Post Code |
```

I'm trying to reproduce this using asp.net. I guess I could manually code up a table to do this, but it seems like there should be a better way. By the looks of it this is not possible with a Gridview, without alot of hacking. I had thought a listview would do what I want, but it seems the grouping in that only lets you group by number of records, not by a parent field.

Is there anyway to do this using a .net control or should I be concentrating on doing it manually with a table and code in the aspx page.

Comment: So you mean group by Country and then County, with a couple of columns of data appearing under that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get a solution using a list view, it's a bit of a hack, but it works well. See [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20210301194237/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/091708-1.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 1):

http://aspalliance.com/1268_CodeSnip_How_to_Group_Data_in_the_GridView_Control.all

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you will be stuck using an HTML table

Use loops to group your data