# Group Repeater for each Distinct User

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, grouping

I have the following repeater item:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RptLeaveRequests" runat="server" 
        onitemdatabound="RptLeaveRequests_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
    <table id="tableItem" runat="server">
        <tr>
                <td style="width: 100px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Date", "{0:dd/M/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 100px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblHours" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Hours") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 200px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPeriod" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("AMorPM") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 200px; font-size:10px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblNote" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Note") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td style="50px">
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtVerified" runat="server" >
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Accept</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">Reject</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

on page load I am binding the Repeater

```
else if(Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserLevel"]) != 0 && Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserLevel"]) < 151)
{
       RptLeaveRequests.DataSource = newLeaveLogic().GetManagerUnverifiedLeaveRequests(Convert.ToInt32(Context.User.Identity.Name));
        RptLeaveRequests.DataBind();
        hasRequests = true;
}
```

Now how can group the Repeater item for each distinct user returned by the GetManagerUnferifiedLeaveRequests which returns a DataTable in the method below:

```
protected void RptLeaveRequests_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
       if (hasRequests)
       {
             //grouping
       }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by grouping?

Comment: group data for each different user. For example a user can have more than one leave request thus the user's name is displayed and underneath it all the requests made by the user, similar to this but instead of Ticker01 and 02 I want the user's name: http://aspnettuts.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/repeater-group.gif?w=595

Comment: There's a full example of something almost identical here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653190/grouped-gridview-with-expandable-groups/11657327#11657327

Comment: @Icarus can you please explain the c# code?

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible solutions:

1) Use nested repeaters:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RptGroups" runat="server" onitemdatabound="RptGroups_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater ID="RptLeaveRequests" runat="server"  onitemdatabound="RptLeaveRequests_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                ...
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

2) Use single repeater for groups and render each group using for example `DataList` or other control for list of items.

In this case you bind list of groups to datasource here:

```
 RptLeaveRequests.DataSource = itemsGroups;
 RptLeaveRequests.DataBind();
```

And bind list of group items here:

```
protected void RptLeaveRequests_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
      //bind here list of group items
}
```

I would prefer the second version.